# NSIS script: Embed an exe inside other exe and extract during installation

Tags: extract, exe, nsis

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "WordFunc.nsh"
 # define the name of the installer
outfile "simple installer.exe"


!macro installVddk

MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL "a.exe is required for installing agent.Do you wish to install it?" IDOK lblinst IDCANCEL abort_inst

abort_inst:
          ABORT
          GoTo lblinst


lblinst:
SetOutPath $EXEDir
;MessageBox MB_OK $OUTDIR
File a.exe
ExecWait "a.exe" $1
!macroend

# default section
section " Agent (required)" main_section
sectionEnd

Function .onInit
    !insertmacro installVddk 
FunctionEnd
```

My question is :

1.I have to keep the a.exe in the same directory as the NSI script during compilation.
How and where do I specify the location from which the a.exe can be picked up, if it is a directory other than the NSI script?

2.If `File a.exe` command is extracting the exe , which code bundles the exe , during compilation .Please help

Comment: It looks for me that in your example b.exe and c.exe are a little bit mixed up, maybe also in your real life problem? Can you update your question to show clearly which file is refered to and where the problem is? Maybe you can show us the part of your code?

Comment: Hi @RolandBär Bär,

Thanks for your reply and yes I have messed up the jar names. Apologies.
Let me try to explain my question properly:

1.I have a NSI script to create an exe (agentInstaller.exe)
2.I want to modify that NSI script to embedd another exe (a.exe) in agentInstaller.exe
3.When the agentInstaller.exe is executed, it should display message to the user "Do you wish to install a.exe?"
If user says OK, then a.exe should be extracted from agentInstaller.exe (in the same directory), and should be 
excuted.

Comment: Please refer the main section of the question - its edited to add code

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation for `File`.

Comment: Hi, Problem resolved ! Now only thing is that I have to keep a.exe in the same directory as the NSI script during compilation. How can specify a location, other than the NSI scripts current location, to pick the exe?

Comment: Just use `File path\to\your\exe`

Comment: My problem of extracting the exe in current directory was resolved by using `SetOutPath $EXEDir`

Comment: @idleberg : Thanks for the help.. but if I use File \path_to_my_exe\, then while executing the exe, it does not extract the a.exe in the current directory

Answer (score 2):

**a.exe** doesn't have to be in the same folder with your **.nsi** script when compiling, but you have to declare the full path in 'File' - consider the following:

```
    SetOutPath $EXEDir
    File "C:\A_folder\a.exe"
    ExecWait "$EXEDir\a.exe"
```

1. with `SetOutPath` you tell where to deploy the file(s) when you run the installer
2. then with `File` you tell NSIS which file(s) to wrap up *(which will then be used during deployment ofc)*